pandas: ошибка "The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version"
Задание
Зафиксируйте состояние генератора случайных чисел с помощью NumPy-функции random.seed(). Аргумент функции совпадает с номером варианта. Сгенерируйте одномерный массив из 1000 значений (закон распределения и его параметры: равномерное с параметрами 0, 1), преобразуйте полученный массив в ряд (Series).Не перезаписывайте переменную sum другими значениями. Отберите из нее элементы по заданным критериям: первый, затем каждый шестой. Сформируйте интервальный ряд с помощью метода .value_counts(), число интервалов: 11. Интервалы по частоте упорядочивать не нужно. Выведите заданный интервал (индекс полученного ряда, преобразованный в строку): 7.
Мой код:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(12)
x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1000)
y = pd.Series(x)
i = pd.Series()
for ind in y.index:
  y.rename(index={ind:'Элемент ' + str(ind + 1)},inplace=True)
sam = y.sample(n = 952)
each6 = pd.Series()
for i in range(len(sam)//6 + 1):
  each6[i] = sam.iloc[i*6]
interval = each6.value_counts(bins=11)
zyz = interval.index[7]
print(zyz)

Выходит следующая ошибка и не получается понять как ее исправить:
Failed. Runtime error

Error:
/sandbox/main.py:6: FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
  i = pd.Series()
/sandbox/main.py:10: FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
  each6 = pd.Series()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3621, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1086, in __setitem__
    self._set_with_engine(key, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1147, in _set_with_engine
    loc = self.index.get_loc(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3623, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sandbox/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    each6[i] = sam.iloc[i*6]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1102, in __setitem__
    self._mgr.setitem_inplace(key, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/base.py", line 177, in setitem_inplace
    self.array[indexer] = value
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Помогите пожалуйста, в чм проблема? Как это исправить?

Код работает без ошибок на Python 3.10, pandas 2.2.2 попробуйте обновить версию pandas pip install -U pandas

Ошибка у вас не там, а в ключе 0 - читайте внимательно текст стека ошибок. FutureWarning - это не ошибка, а предупреждение об изменении в работе метода в будущих версиях pandas.

Странно вы извлекаете каждый шестой элемент. Срезы не проходили? each6 = y[::6]
